# gedit automatic session saving

Tags: gedit, plugins

I am using gedit on Ubuntu machine. Suppose if I open gedit and open some files say - file1.txt & file2.txt , then after if I close the gedit and reopen once again then it is creating a new session instead of opening the previous files - file1.txt & file2.txt

I tried installing gmate using this link - https://github.com/gmate/gmate#readme, but when I go to Edit --> Preferences then I got an error saying `Error: Plugin loader "python" was not found.`. So I used this link - https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/153 and updated my plugin file with `Loader = python3`. Then I started getting another error as

> ** (gedit:17302): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found
>   ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gedit Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/restoretabs/restoretabs.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from gi.repository import GObject, GLib, Gtk, Gio, Gedit ImportError: cannot import name Gedit
>
> (gedit:17302): libpeas-WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'restoretabs'

I am keep on getting so many errors, after searching in internet for a long time I came to this point. Please help me how can I fix this.